# Arithmetic sequence to geometric sequence.

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, contest-math

> The numbers $a_1, a_2, a_3, . . .$ form an arithmetic sequence with $a_1 \ne a_2$. The three
>   numbers $a_1, a_2, a_6$ form a geometric sequence in that order. Determine all possible
>   positive integers $k$ for which the three numbers $a_1, a_4, a_k$ also form a geometric
>   sequence in that order.

This is from Euclid 2015:[Problem 7B](http://cemc.uwaterloo.ca/contests/past_contests/2015/2015EuclidContest.pdf)

I got that:

$a_n = a_1 + (n-1)d = r^{n-1} a_1$ where $d$ is difference, and $r$ the geom. ratio.

But this doesnt give many leads, **HINTS ONLY PLEASE.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT :

Use the fact that
$$\text{$a,b,c$ form a geometric sequence}\Rightarrow b^2=ac$$

Thus, you have
$$a_2^2=a_1a_6\quad\text{and}\quad a_4^2=a_1a_k$$

Express these by $a_1$ and $d$.

Comment: thanks (+1). I got: $a_1^2 + 2a_1d + d^2 = a_1 (a_1 + 5d)$ and $a_1^2 + 6a_1 d + 9d^2 = a_1 a_k$.  The first yields, $a_1^2 + 2a_1d + d^2 - a_1^2 - 5a_1d = 0 \implies -3a_1 d + d^2 = 0 \implies d(d - 3a_1) = 0$ so $3a_1 = d$. Plugging to the second, $a_1^2 + 18a_1^2 + 81a_1^2 = a_1 a_k$ so $ a_k = 100a_1$. So will $k=99$? I got the value for $a_k$, but not $k$ itself.

Comment: @Amad27: $d=3a_1$ is correct. Then, you have $(a_1+3d)^2=a_1(a_1+(k-1)d)$, i.e. $(a_1+9a_1)^2=a_1(a_1+(k-1)\cdot 3a_1)$. You'll get $k=34$. Write $a_k$ as $a_1+(k-1)d$.

Comment: Mmmm.. should have seen that. Thanks for helping!

Comment: @Amad27: You are welcome.